# "undefined method `each'" occurs in one-to-many association in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a association between two Models: User and Task, `User has_many Tasks`, and `Task belongs_to User`. In theory, this will generate `User.tasks` and `User.tasks=` these new methods can be used. However, when I execute the tests in the Rails console, I have an inexplicable problem:

```
> u1 = User.find_by_id(1)
> t1 = Task.new(name:"MY NEW TASK")
> u1.tasks = t1
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):7
        1: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<Task:0x00007f2f0446f570>
```

Does this mean there is something wrong with the association between the two Models? How should I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `u1.tasks = [t1]`?

Comment: @BenStephens ```ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to replace tasks because one or more of the new records could not be saved.)```

Comment: Does `Task.new(name:"MY NEW TASK")` meet the validations you have on the Task model? Does `u1.tasks[0].errors` have a value? (After doing `u1.tasks = [t1]`.)

Comment: Now I arbitrarily created a task, but I found that it is not associated with user_id, which makes me unable to see the information on the webpage in the case of current_user
```> Task.all
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Task id: 26, name: "aaa增加的", note: "AAAAA", due_date: "2022-03-29 20:07:00.000000000 +0800", priority: "high", status: "carry_on", user_id: nil, created_at: "2022-03-27 20:08:00.148292000 +0800", updated_at: "2022-03-27 20:08:00.148292000 +0800">]>```

Comment: `u1.tasks.create(name: "...")`

Comment: Thank you, but I have two questions. 1. How is the ```.tasks.create``` method created? 2. Why is ```.tasks.all``` invalid?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a `has_many` assocation the `others=` setter it creates expects the value to be an array, ActiveRecord::Relation or generally any object that responds to `#each`. Its is after all an assocation with MANY other objects - not a single object.

It would work if you actually wrote:

```
u1 = User.find_by_id(1)
t1 = Task.new(name:"MY NEW TASK")
u1.tasks = [t1]
```

But thats not very idiomatic and will remove any other tasks which you probably don't want.

The idiomatic way to create a unsaved record off a `has_many` assocation is:

```
u1 = User.find_by_id(1)
t1 = u1.tasks.new(name:"MY NEW TASK")
```

If you want to add a single existing record to an assocation on an object you can use the "shovel" method:

```
u1 = User.find_by_id(1)
t1 = Task.new(name:"MY NEW TASK")
u1.tasks << t1
```

This will save the record though.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the user directly when you create a task:

```
u1 = User.find_by_id(1)
t1 = Task.new(name:"MY NEW TASK", user: u1)
```

Alternatively, create a task via `u1.tasks`:

```
u1.tasks.create(name:"MY NEW TASK")
```

You should consider adding a validator to require a task is always created with a user. I assume that it doesn't make sense to create tasks that aren't assigned to a user. A validator can enforce this so you get an error when you try to create a task without a user.